Minimizing the L1 norm of Ax - b using scipy.optimize.linprog
It is known that the problem of minimizing the 1-norm of Ax - b over x can be written as a linear programming problem. I would like to use scipy.optimize.linprog to solve this minimization problem, but I am having trouble interpreting the output array of linprog. Below is my code implementation of the method to solve Ax - b via linear programming:
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op
from scipy.linalg import lstsq

def build_A_ub(A):
    Nrow, Ncol = A.shape
    I          = np.identity(Nrow)

    return np.block([
        [A , -I],
        [-A, -I]
    ])

def build_b_ub(b):
    return np.concatenate([b, -b])

def build_c(A):
    Nrow, Ncol = A.shape
    return np.concatenate([np.zeros(Ncol), np.ones(Nrow)])

def obtain_l1norm_minimizer(A, b):
    """
    return op_result which contains parameters x which minimizes |Ax - b|_1
    """
    A_ub, b_ub, c = build_A_ub(A), build_b_ub(b), build_c(A)
    
    return op.linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub)

This sometimes works. For example, in the following case where the minimal 1-norm is 0, we have:
#
#    example implementation of L1 norm minimization of Ax - b for n x m matrix 
#    with n < m and rank(n) (i.e: exact solution to Ax - b)
#

from numpy.random import uniform

np.random.seed(2)
Nrow = 3
Ncol = 4
A    = uniform(-1, 1, [Nrow,Ncol])
b    = uniform(-1, 1, [Nrow])

assert np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) == min([Nrow, Ncol])

op_result  = obtain_l1norm_minimizer(A, b)
difference = A @ op_result.x[:Ncol] - b

print("Solution vector (x,y):")
print(np.round(op_result.x, 6))
print("Ax - b:")
print(np.round(difference, 6))

produces output
Solution vector (x,y):
[1.366741 0.373728 0.       1.557993 0.       0.       0.      ]
Ax - b:
[ 0. -0.  0.]

However, in the following problem where there is no exact solution, it does not produce a vector with minimal 1-norm:
np.random.seed(2)
Nrow = 6
Ncol = 3
A    = uniform(-1, 1, [Nrow,Ncol])
b    = uniform(-1, 1, [Nrow])

assert np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) == min([Nrow, Ncol])

op_result        = obtain_l1norm_minimizer(A, b)
x_lstsq, _, _, _ = lstsq(A, b)

# compare 1-norm of original, solution obtained from 1-norm minimization, and least squares solution

print(f'original 1-norm : {np.linalg.norm(b, 1)}')
print(f'1-norm from 1-norm minimization: {np.linalg.norm(A @ op_result.x[:Ncol] - b, 1)}')
print(f'1-norm from least-squares minimization : {np.linalg.norm(A @ x_lstsq - b, 1)}')

with output
original 1-norm : 3.364444701650462
1-norm from 1-norm minimization: 3.2226922553095174
1-norm from least-squares minimization : 2.374926794178961

Therefore, my implementation only sometimes give the right answer. Empirically, for systems in which there is an exact solution, I find that the answer is correct if and only if all the non-zero entries of the output op_result.x are in the first Ncol entries. When this isn't true, there doesn't seem to be any method to obtain a solution from op_result.x; I tried, for example, permuting all the entries and seeing if the permuted parameters generated a solution. My question is: why is my implementation only sometimes working and what can I modify to make it always work?

"example implementation of L1 norm minimization of Ax - b for n x m matrix with n > m and rank(m) (i.e: exact solution to Ax - b)" - in your example, n (the number of rows) < m (the number of columns), and it is of rank m. Did you mean an m x n matrix?

Thanks for catching that. I've edited it.

Alternatively, you can remove the bounds from your decision variables. By default, they must be non-negative. Presumably you intended for them to be unbounded, though, so:
op.linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, bounds=(None, None))

I haven't checked your code carefully since there is a better way to solve such a problem, but this seems to work.

It seems like this works, in the sense that the answer I get always has lower 1-norm compared with the least-squares solution.

Since you have fewer equations than unknowns, you can modify it to always work by using scipy.linalg.lstsq instead.
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import uniform
from scipy.linalg import lstsq
np.random.seed(0)
Nrow = 3
Ncol = 4
A = uniform(-1, 1, [Nrow,Ncol])
b = uniform(-1, 1, [Nrow])
x, _, _, _ = lstsq(A, b)
print(A@x - b)
# [-2.77555756e-17  3.33066907e-16 -2.22044605e-16]

If you are interested in problems which do not have an exact solution, provide an example with that feature.

Thanks for the response! I've included an example in which my code breaks for a problem with no exact solution, which is the case I'm interested in.

Did you try my second answer, setting the bounds to (None, None)? That seems to fix this problem, too.
